# Flutter Stepper Vertical/Horizontal Overflow

Tags: flutter, overflow, horizontal-scrolling, stepper

I have Stepper more then 3 Steps.

Stepper Working Properly `Vertical` direction but when i switch `Horizontal` with `FloatingActionButton` then **Overflow** Pixel.

Attached **ScreenShot:-**

[image][image]

My **Code:-**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StepperEx extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StepperExState createState() => _StepperExState();
}

class _StepperExState extends State<StepperEx> {
  int _currentStep = 0;
  StepperType stepperType = StepperType.vertical;

  switchStepType() {
    setState(() => stepperType == StepperType.vertical
        ? stepperType = StepperType.horizontal
        : stepperType = StepperType.vertical);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Stepper Example'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Stepper(
              //physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              steps: _stepper(),
              type: stepperType,
              currentStep: this._currentStep,
              onStepTapped: (step) {
                setState(() {
                  this._currentStep = step;
                });
              },
              onStepContinue: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (this._currentStep < this._stepper().length - 1) {
                    this._currentStep = this._currentStep + 1;
                  } else {
                    //Logic
                    print('complete');
                  }
                });
              },
              onStepCancel: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (this._currentStep > 0) {
                    this._currentStep = this._currentStep - 1;
                  } else {
                    this._currentStep = 0;
                  }
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.swap_horizontal_circle),
        onPressed: switchStepType,
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Step> _stepper() {
    List<Step> _steps = [
      Step(
          title: Text('Name'),
          content: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          isActive: _currentStep >= 0,
          state: StepState.complete),
      Step(
          title: Text('Email'),
          content: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email Address'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Recovery Email'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          isActive: _currentStep >= 1,
          state: StepState.disabled),
      Step(
          title: Text('Mobile No.'),
          content: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Mobile No.'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration:
                    InputDecoration(labelText: 'Alternative Mobile No.'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          isActive: _currentStep >= 2,
          state: StepState.editing),
      Step(
          title: Text('Address'),
          content: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address 1'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Address 2'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          isActive: _currentStep >= 3,
          state: StepState.error),
      Step(
          title: Text('Password'),
          content: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Confirm Password'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          isActive: _currentStep >= 4,
          state: StepState.indexed),
    ];
    return _steps;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an issue with flutter's stepper implementation. Refer to https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40601 for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vineet mentioned its an Issue in the Stepper. 
There is also a Project (called fa_stepper) u can use to have a scrollable bar:

https://github.com/dipnv/flutter_stepper/tree/master/horizontal_stepper